# Is there any software to control at what time a specific network can be used?

Tags: network, wifi

I recently purchased a MiFi to be used while commuting, but apparently the AutoOn doesn't really work as expected.

In less than a week I bursted £16 pound credit, when I was supposed to pay £0.2 per each 20Mb.
As I did not downloaded 1.6GB of traffic, but I don't have time to complain I wonder whether there is some way or some software to control at what time my laptop use a specific network.

By doing this, even though the MiFi will remain active, no network will be connected and I won't be charged (though it is also strange I have made traffic with the laptop off).

Look forward to hearing from you.
Andrea

Comment: what is a MiFi?

Comment: A MiFi is a portable GSM device that allows you to connect on Internet using a SIM card.

Comment: I know Airport utility does that but that does not help you.http://9to5mac.com/2013/10/06/how-to-set-time-limits-on-your-wi-fi-network-using-airport-utility/

Comment: I think you want something that tells you once you have used certain amount of data, then at least yiu know and can decide to continue or not. The problem is that there are background apps that are sucking up on your network without letting you know.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app called Control Plane that allows you to setup rules for various preferences based on criteria such as what network you just joined, your location, time of day, etc. You could try creating a rule with it that cuts down the network activity on your mac after so many minutes of connecting to the Mifi.

http://www.controlplaneapp.com